# jekyll: Deploy to webserver

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have built the site using `jekyll`. Everything works on my local mac when I do `jekyll serve` and use localhost:4000. As the jekyll site explains I have scp the content of _site folder to the `.www` folder in the webserver that I have access to, but I don't get any of the look and field. I wonder if there is anything that I am missing.

Its a NFS file system and I have a account in the system. Each user get .www folder to host their website I have used scp to push the content of the _site folder to .www folder. I after coping the files I have give 775 as permission to all the files and directories.

Comment: What web-server are you using? Did you configure correctly? is a VPS? What commandline are you using to upload it? are the files shown on the server (e.g. via ssh) but on on the web server?

Comment: The question is very hard to debug. Provide the link to the site. If you open the content of the _site folder in a browser, does it work?

Comment: Yes when I ssh I see all the files. I think its a apache base server but its a NFS file system. All I did was scp the content of _site.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti yes I can access the files in public folder but I can't access about etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check the _config.yml file. See if the URL or BaseURL is set to `http://localhost:4000`. It it is, simply change it back to your domain address.

Comment: I have set it up for my domain address.